# Recursive function based on 2 conditions

Tags: recursion

I want to write a recursive function which exits on 2 conditions.

Let's say I want to make a directory and ask the user for input. He may enter something like this:

```
Valid: /existing-dir1/existing-DIR2/non-existence-dir1/non-existence-dir2
Invalid: /existing-dir1/existing-FILE1/non-existence-dir1/non-existence-dir2
```

To loop through the filename, I have the function `dirname()` which take `/foo/bar` and returns `/foo`. I also have function `exist()` to check if a filename exist and `isdir()` to see if it is a file or directory.

Basically, I need to loop recursively from the end of the filename, ignore non-existence nodes, and check if any node is a file - which is invalid. The recursion ends when one of the 2 conditions happens, whichever comes first:

1. A file is found
2. `dirname()` returns `/`

I am not familiar with recursion, and 2 conditions is a bit too much for me. I am using POSIX script but code samples in C++ / Java / C# are all good.

Edit: I know I can do a `mkdir -p` and get its status code, but it will create the directory. Nontheless, I want to do that in recursion for the purpose of learning.

Comment: Why do you want to loop through from the end?  It seems to me that if you start from the beginning, you can return `invalid` if any prefix path represents a file, and `valid` if you get through the whole string without encountering a file.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Probably because of the pre-installed `dirname` program, which is suitable for looping from the end. In shell scripting, tools are limited, even array is not available. Looping from the beginning may make the code a bit more complicated. I prefer to go with what are already available.

Comment: I suppose the recursion is much the same from the end.

Answer (score 1):

In JS, you might write the recursion like this:

```js
const isValid = (path) => 
  path === '/' 
    ? 'valid' 
    : exist(path) && !isdir(path) 
      ? 'invalid' 
      : isValid(dirname(path))
```

You might be able to skip the `exist` check depending upon how your `isdir` function works.

This should show the logic, but I'm not sure how to write this in your Posix script environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am familiar with C-like syntax and can't quite understand the code above. However I did manage to solve it myself after 15mins or so. I spent 2 hours this afternoon and end up with no clue how to do it before going here to ask.

Comment: Now I am thinking of a 3rd condition, that is the bottom level directory (first found existing directory when loop from the end) must be writable. Guess I'll do that myself this time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. Written in POSIX script, but it is quite easy to read and port to other languages:

```
RecursivelyCheckFilename ()
{
    if [ -e "$1" ]  # if exists
    then
        if [ -d "$1" ]  # if is directory
        then
            if [ "$1" = "/" ]
            then
                return 0;
            else
                RecursivelyCheckFilename "$(dirname -- "$1")";
                return $?;  # returns the value returned by previous function
            fi
        else
            return 1;
        fi
    else
        RecursivelyCheckFilename "$(dirname -- "$1")";
        return $?;
    fi
}
```

There are still a few issues with filename ending with a trailing slash, which I must find a way to deal with. But the code above is how I want it to work.